# Fivetran - CDC vs Fivetran Teleport

Tags: architecture

I am configuring Fivetran between many MS SQL servers and a snowflake database.
I came across two transport option: using CDC and Fivetran Teleport.
Fivetran Teleport is fairly new technology that only requires a readonly user and I am not familiar with the downside of it. While CDC has a lot of downside like eating up memory on the SQL server, making the backup file bigger, etc plus a lot of configuration.

In your experience, which is the better option for a long term production system, where we transfer data daily? Does Fivetran Teleport has issues we have to consider in the decision?

[image]